# Alternative proof for localization isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $f$ be an $A$-module morphism and $\operatorname{res}_{A_m}^A$ be the restriction of scalars functor from $A_m$-mod to $A$-mod.

I'm curious if you have proven that for every maximal ideal $m\lhd A$, $\operatorname{res}_{A_m}^A(f_m)$ is an isomorphism .. then can you conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism?

(I know of a short proof relying on an argument via the annihilator of a non-zero element of $\ker(f)$ and $\operatorname{coker}(f)$ to prove that $f$ is an iso. if each $f_m$ is but I'm curious if this alternative approach yields any conclusion)

Comment: I don't really see the difference between the two approaches. $\operatorname{res}^A_{A_m}(f_m)$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f_m$ is.

Comment: I want to show $f$ is an isomorphism if $res_{A_m)^A(f_m)$ is for each maximal ideal $m$ of $A$.. i was thinking of using a projective limit.. but I dont believe that functor is exact in general..